# Change browser encoding with PHP?

Tags: php, browser, encoding

I've got a program on which I have non-ASCII characters which do not show properly on ISO-8859-1. Is there a way to use PHP and change the browser encoding somehow, and also allow the characters to display properly in the browser even though the encoding is ISO-8859-1?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: So if it's not ISO-8859-1, what *is* the charset?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [header](http://php.net/header) function to send an (explicit) [HTTP Content-Type response header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17).

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

… replacing ISO-8859-1 with whatever encoding you are actually using. Hopefully that will be UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the [`header`](http://fr.php.net/header) function

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Note: you should make sure no content have been sent to the browser or you can't modify the headers anymore, so I advise you to use this code as soon as possible in your script

Answer (score 2):

The browser itself doesn't have an encoding. It supports many encodings and uses the one you tell it too. If you specify (in headers and/or HTML) that the encoding is ISO-8859-1, then your document should be in that encoding and you should make sure that all characters you send are in the right encoding. So you should actually send ISO-8859-1 characters. You cannot send a document that uses different encodings for different sections of the document.

For some characters, you may post an HTML entity instead. For instance `é` can be sent as `&eacute;`. This will work, regardless of encoding.

If you have the choice, I'd opt to use UTF-8. It supports any character and you don't have to worry about escaping diacritics or other special characters, except those that are special to HTML/XML itself.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, using the [header](http://php.net/header) function:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

or, if you want to serve valid `XHTML` files instead of the standard `HTML`:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml+xhtml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

It is possible to call the header later on in the script, unlike what [RageZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169442/ragez) said, but you will need to have enabled [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) for that, using `ob_start()`.

Comment: The registered MIME type for XHTML is `application/xml+xhtml` there is no `text/xhtml`.

Comment: You have a syntax error in both examples as you fail to terminate the string in either.

Comment: Fixed the XHTML content-type, and the strings are being terminated properly. Sorry about that :P